# Can i have more than one form for front end posting in one template

Tags: posts, front-end

I'm building a front end post form for car dealing. I have the "if statement validation" at the begining of my template, before get_header() function, after that i have the form. Can i have two or more forms in that template without a conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can check which form is being submitted by adding a "name" attribute to the submit button.

```
<input type="submit" name="form1" value="Submit">
```

Then in you validation, just check if that exists:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['form1'])){
    // Form 1
} elseif(isset($_REQUEST['form2'])) {
    // Form 2
}
```

This is one method at least, there are plenty of ways to deal with it.

Comment: Thank you very much, James! That was exacly what i needed!